# Relation between kahler potential and Hermitian metric

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a Kaehler manifold and $h$ be its Hermitian form, then in local sense we can write $$\omega=\partial\bar\partial\log h$$ and also if $f$ be the kaehler potential then we can write $$\omega=\partial\bar\partial\log f$$. So, my question is can say $f$ is equal to $h$ up to additional constant? if we have $f$ then how can we find $h$

Comment: What's the Hermition (sic?) form of a Kahler metric?

Comment: Gunnar , I mean was hermitian form

Comment: But what is the "Hermitian form" of a Kahler manifold? When I google it, it is defined to be the $(1,1)$-form $\omega$.

Comment: Here you can see in equation 1.11. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/039304409090019Y $h$ is hermitian structure

Comment: I guess $h$ here is $g=h+i\omega$,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $\psi:=\log(fh^{-1})$ satisfies $\partial\bar\partial \psi=0$, because $ \partial\bar\partial\log f=\partial\bar\partial\log h =\omega$.
Such functions are called pluriharmonic. Locally a pluriharmonic function is a real part of a holomorphic function, by Poincare-Dolbeault-Grothendieck lemma. 
This fact is true globally, because any real-valued holomorphic function vanishes, and therefore the local holomorphic functions can be glued together. Then, $h$ is unique (up to a constant multiplier) if and only if the manifold has no non-constant global holomorphic functions.

Comment: The question here is if $h(s_1,s_2)$ (with sections $s_i$)be hermitian structure then how can we find $h$ by using kahler potential $f$?

Comment: If $h$ is the Hermitian form, what is the meaning of $\log h$?

Comment: It makes no sense, of course; I assumed that the poster confused a metric with its potential

Comment: See http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/039304409090019Y in equation 1.11, IN FACT , $h$ is hermitian metric corresponding to hermitian form, so $\log h$ here must means $\log \hat h$ which $\hat h$ is hermitian metric corresponding to hermitian form in local trivialization

Comment: I don't have access to this article; but anyway, $dd^c$ cannot be applied to metric, or to its logarithm.